# SSRS Report - Horizontally Sort Columns Across Column Groups

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an unusual SSRS report that requires that the user be able to use parameters to select which of the (more than 250) fields appear in the report. So the number of columns in this report can vary greatly.

I've been mostly successful at implementing this, but am stuck at controlling how to change the order of the columns.

Here is (a simplified example) of my original data:
[My data as a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN0Tw.jpg)

**CompanyID | Address       | Website_URL   | Date_Created | Date Modified |**
1           |123 Main Street|www.fake.com   | 3/14/2019    | 3/15/2019     |
2           |555 Park Ave   |www.notreal.com|3/12/2019     | 3/13/2019     |

The first thing I've done is to unpivot my data within my dataset  (i used cross apply to do this). The name of what the column used to be is kept in a column named something like "Col_1", and the value is kept in a column named something like "Val_1". The trick is, I have to do this multiple times, once for each data type that I'm dealing with. Because obviously you can't have dates and nvarchars in the same column. When I unpivot the data above, it looks like this:

**CompanyID | Col_1       | Val_1           | Col_2 | Val_2 |**

1           |Address      |123 Main Street  | Date_Created    | 3/14/2019    |
1           |Website_URL   |www.fake.com    |Date Modified    | 3/15/2019    |
2           |Address       |555 Park Ave    |Date_Created     |3/12/2019     |
2           |Website_URL   |www.notreal.com |Date Modified    |3/13/2019     |

The point in doing this is now I can create a matrix is the SSRS report with the CompanyID as a row group. Then I create two adjacent column groups for Col_1, and Col_2, which have as their values Val_1 and Val_2, respectively.
[Click here to see SSRS Groupings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntCLt.png)

Now, when this report runs, each column group (for example, Col_1) expands out to show all the column names I had under that column in my unpivoted data. This could be dozens of columns. This picture shows what my final data looks like. This is similar to what my original data looked like. But with the benefit of the fact that the columns are being displayed dynamically.

[My resulting Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DcB.jpg)

So, the only problem I'm having is that the columns are stuck *within* their groups. Say I want to sort them alphabetically, I can only sort the nvarchars together, and the dates together. I cannot sort the *across* their groups. Is there a way I can do this?

[The resulting Matrix I want, with columns sorted alphabetically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki7ST.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using your original unpivoted data, the design of your report needs to have 4 column groups.

1.Address
2.Date created
3.Date modified
4.Website URL

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I might not be understanding. Are you saying that I need to manually create a column group in the tablix for each column I want? Or is there a way to do that dynamically? The reason for the whole weird design is that in my actual report, there are not just 4 columns. It varies between 2 columns and more than 100, choosing from over 250 possible columns based on logic within the dataset. This was the only way I knew of to create a tablix with a variable number of columns.